# Format and split csv/json on php

Tags: php, json, split, format

I'm trying to consume this API to populate my mysql database, and i need to update if "new itens" appear, and update all the prices. I already have the back-end structure to this scripts, but i need to split the name from the price of every item.

API (you can open on browser): https://api.csgofast.com/price/all

How can i do that, like, the best way?

I tried to explode on ":", but the're cases like that:

```
"Prismatic: Miasmatic Grey": 39.48,
```

So the explode doesn't work.

Thanks in advice.

The code:

```
protected function populateItems()
{
    $items = json_decode(file_get_contents(API_URL));
    foreach($items as $item) {
        Item::create([
            'name' => $i[0],
            'price' => $i[1]
        ]);
    }
    die('end');
}
```

And i tried this too, but it fails on the ":"

```
protected function populateItems()
{
    $body = file_get_contents(API_URL);
    $items_parsed = str_replace('{', '', $body);
    $items_converted = str_replace('}', '', $items_parsed);
    $items = str_getcsv($items_converted);
    foreach($items as $item) {
        // Item::create([
            // 'name' => $i[0],
            // 'price' => $i[1]
        // ]);
    }
    echo 'Fim da execução.';
    die;
}
```

Answer response:

```
object(stdClass)#470 (15689) { ["Sticker | Counter Logic Gaming (Foil) | MLG 
Columbus 2016"]=> float(2.14) ["Sticker | RUBINO (Foil) | Cologne 2016"]=> 
float(1.26) ["P2000 | Granite Marbleized (Well-Worn)"]=> float(0.01) ["★ Bayonet 
| Fade (Minimal Wear)"]=> float(226.55)
```

Comment: Please include an example of the API response into the question itself together with the code you've tried, the expected result, and the result it currently produces. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why can't you just json_decode all data?

Comment: If i json_decode, i got this answer

    object(stdClass)#470 (15689) { ["Sticker | Counter Logic Gaming (Foil) | MLG Columbus 2016"]=> float(2.14) ["Sticker | RUBINO (Foil) | Cologne 2016"]=> float(1.26) ["P2000 | Granite Marbleized (Well-Worn)"]=> float(0.01) ["★ Bayonet | Fade (Minimal Wear)"]=> float(226.55) 

Isn't to easy to manipulate that, or is?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the problem. I wasn't used to use a for each with $key => $value, so i solved this way:

```
$items = json_decode(file_get_contents(API_URL));
    foreach($items as $item => $price) {
        Item::create([
            'name' => $item,
            'price' => $price
        ]);
    }
```